# Ошибка выборки из базы при использовании функции mysql_fetch_row

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу скрипт, вот он: `$tmp = mysql_fetch_row ($select);`, на сервере выдаёт ошибку? Почему?

```
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($myrow['col'] > 2) 
{ 
   exit("Вы набрали логин или пароль неверно 3 раз. Подождите 15 минут до следующей попытки."); 
} 
$password = md5($password); 
$password = strrev($password); 
$password = $password."b3p6f"; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Ошибка:

> `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in Z:homephpwwwtestreg.php on line 8
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in Z:homephpwwwtestreg.php on line 17
> Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in Z:homephpwwwtestreg.php on line 21`

Comment: всегда пишите текст ошибки и форматируйе код скрипта

Comment: @антон, Отредактируйте вопрос. В данный момент ничего не ясно.

Comment: "Помогите пишу скрипт вот он $tmp = mysql_fetch_row ($select);"
$tmp = mysql_fetch_row ($select); -то есть это скрипт?
На сервере выдает ошибку! Какую ошибку выдает сервер? Зачем половина кода? Выложите нужный кусок! Или точнее изъясняйтесь)

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Comment: @антон Какую какая ошибка возникает на сервере?

Comment: Текст ошибки добавлен в вопрос.

Comment: @антон Выложите весь код!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in Z:homephpwwwtestreg.php on line 8
```

намекает на то что

```
$tmp = mysql_fetch_row ($select);, // как бы сначала нужно сделать запрос
```

примерно так

```
$select="SELECT * FROM table WHERE blah-bla";
$result=mysql_query($select);
// ну а дальше по сценарию делать что нужно.
```

Answer (score 0):

Запрос составлен не правильно, переменные так не подставляются в запрос, я обчно делал так:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE login='" . mysql_real_escape_string($login) . "' AND password='" . mysql_real_escape_string($password) ."'"
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```